# How to get that graph in plotly?

Tags: dataframe, plotly-python

I have hourly data time series for 2016 till 2020 and I want to get a graph looks like the attached picture[image]

```
datetime              Demand
2016-1-1 01:00:00.    500
2016-1-1 02:00:00.    450
2016-1-1 03:00:00.    650
.........................
2017-1-1 01:00:00.    570
2017-1-1 02:00:00.    470
2017-1-1 03:00:00.    600
.........................
.........................
2020-1-1 01:00:00.    900
2020-1-1 02:00:00.    800
2020-1-1 03:00:00.    950
```

My dataframe looks like aboved dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll need to create two new columns for your dataframe
Year and Hour.
You can use datetime in order to do that.
With those two columns you can now create a px.line graph where x is your Hour column, where Y is your Demand column and where color is your Year column.

References:
[Datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
[Line Charts With Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/)

Comment: Thanks Jorge but how to add vertical lines and in between texts ?

Comment: The image is no longer available. Could you please post it again?